# CREATE ASSEMBLY in UNSAFE mode with File path does not create Functions in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlclr

I am trying to register CLR assembly in SQL Server with following statement:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLCLRTest
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 'C:\MyApp\SQLCLRTest.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

The CLR assembly is signed with a pfx key, and I have already created an Asymmetric key and a SQL login like to allow installing this particular assembly with UNSAFE permissions set.

The problem is that above statement creates the assembly in database, but it doesn't show up any sql server functions I have created in the assembly.

I dont see any issue with my CLR assembly, because when I publish the database through SQL Server Database project in Visual Studio I can see all functions getting created in the database. When I looked into the Publish scripts, I could see the database project uses Binary of the assembly. That means, it executes something like

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLCLRTest
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF000.......
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

So my questions is why the assembly gets registered properly through the DLL binaries, but not when I use DLL's path?

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Database server: SQL Server 2012. Database project is created in Visual Studio 2013. CLR assembly is created as a separate class library project in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Adding the assembly and registering/adding the functions within it should be two separate steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the assembly gets registered properly through the DLL binaries, but not when I use DLL's path?

The issue is not the creation (what you are referring to as getting registered) of the assembly. If you do not get an error when running `CREATE ASSEMBLY` then it did get created successfully.

But, the assembly itself merely contains the .NET methods that *can* be referenced by T-SQL wrapper objects, but creating an assembly does not automagically create those T-SQL wrapper objects. Those need to be explicitly created.

The main publish script used by SSDT is a diff / incremental script to bring the target DB up to the state implied by your project. If you want to always get the CREATE statements regardless of any changes being deployed, be sure to:

1. Definitely check the "Generate DDL" option on the "SQLCLR" tab of Project Properties. This option controls whether or not the wrapper object CREATE statements (i.e. the `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE TYPE`, `CREATE AGGREGATE`, and `CREATE TRIGGER` statements) are generated.
2. Optionally check the "Create script (.sql file)" check-box on the "Project Settings" tab of Project Properties. With this checked, each time you do a build there will be a **{Build tab.BuildOutputPath}\{Build tab.BuildOutputFileName}_Create.sql** script. That **_Create.sql** script will always contain the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement.

When you do a build, there will always be a **obj\Debug\{SQLCLR tab.AssemblyName}.generated.sql** script. That script will always contain the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement. That script will also contain the `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE TYPE`, `CREATE AGGREGATE`, and `CREATE TRIGGER` statements IF you have the "Generate DDL" option checked (#1 above). This script is not exactly runnable as it is out of order, but the statements in this script are used to generate the Publish and optional Create scripts.

If you have the "Create script" option checked (#2 above), then, assuming that you also have the "Generate DDL" option checked (#1 again), the `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE TYPE`, `CREATE AGGREGATE`, and `CREATE TRIGGER` statements will also be in a **{Build tab.BuildOutputPath}\{Build tab.BuildOutputFileName}_Create.sql** script. In this script, the statements will be in the correct order.

Comment: To clarify slightly: when you build a Database Project containing SQLCLR code, it will auto-generate the necessary DDL to wrap your .Net methods. This is included in a .generated.sql file and can be found in the project's obj folder. Project Publish will handle this correctly but if you want to manually deploy you'd need to execute these statements to link in the Assembly

Comment: @KevinCunnane Thanks. I clarified the clarification ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The publish step from Visual Studio also includes a *separate* script to create the functions and procedures embedded in your SQLCLR assembly. As a result, Visual Studio is doing both of these jobs for you.

Execution of the CREATE ASSEMBLY script does *not* create the functions or procs. It merely exposes the assembly to the SQLCLR. You must create them manually/separately when creating the assembly in the manner.